# ajax not working on rails 4

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I've looked everywhere but can't seem to find the problem why my AJAX request is not going through for adding items to Cart.

line_items_controller.rb

```
def create
  product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
  @line_item = @cart.add_product(product.id)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @line_item.save
      format.html { redirect_to store_url }
      format.js   { @current_item = @line_item }
      format.json { render action: 'show',
                           status: :created, location: @line_item }
    else
      format.html { render action: 'new' }
      format.json { render json: @line_item.errors,
                           status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

store/index.html.erb

```
       <% if notice %>
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<% end %>

<h1>Your Pragmatic Catalog</h1>

<% cache ['store', Product.latest] do %>
<% @products.each do |product| %>
    <% cache ['entry', product] do %>
        <div class="entry">
          <%= image_tag(product.image_url) %>
          <h3><%= product.title %></h3>
          <%= sanitize(product.description) %>
          <div class="price_line">
            <span class="price"><%= number_to_currency(product.price) %></span>
            <%= button_to 'Add to Cart', line_items_path(product_id: product),
                          remote: true %>
          </div>
        </div>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

line_items/create.js.erb

```
$('#cart').html("<%= escape_javascript render(@cart) %>");

$('#current_item').css({'background-color':'#88ff88'}).
    animate({'background-color':'#114411'}, 1000);
```

line_items/_line_item.html.erb

```
 <% if line_item == @current_item %>
<tr id="current_item">
<% else %>
<tr>
<% end %>
<td> <%= line_item.quantity %>&times; </td>
<td> <%= line_item.product.title %> </td>
 <td class= "item_price" > <%= number_to_currency(line_item.total_price) %> </td>
</tr>
```

I can see in my log file that page sends a bunch of GET requests every time I add an item to the cart and also I can see it reload. No errors found in the log file.

restarted the site several times. checked if I have jquery and jquery-ui gems installed properly. Nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

try specifying

method: :post

in the button_to call.  A get request isn't going to trigger the create method.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling create action of line_items_controller.rb and create action is a POST action.

So add `method: :post`  in this

```
<%= button_to 'Add to Cart', line_items_path(product_id: product), method: :post
                          remote: true %>
```

And try to debug in create action that is it calling or not.

Comment: I tried post, it didn't help. I didn't mean that I see GET requests for that particular action. I meant that the page gets rendered again all the time by making GET requests to images, stylesheets etc. I can see that the create request is post. it just doesn't use AJAX

Comment: is "#cart" div is present on the page ?

Answer (score 0):

Include these two JavaScript files on top of partial:

```
javascript_include_tag "jquery", "jquery_ujs"
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have forgot to define `@cart` in `create` action.
Just add `@cart = current_cart`